# AddApacheModRewrite method suggesting that file doesn't exist (when it does)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-3.1

Just trying to put an ApacheModRewrite call in my .NET Core 3.1 web application, and no matter what I do, it keeps telling me that the file does not exist.  I've verified that the file exists at that location, I've tried creating a custom PhysicalFileProvider, and I've tried to set the file as Content/Copy Always, but no matter what I do, I cannot get past this code:

```
 var options = new RewriteOptions()
          .AddApacheModRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, env.ContentRootPath + ".htaccess");
```

And the error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The file F:\Source\MyWebsite\htaccess.txt does not exist.'

Where env.ContentRootFileProvider resolves to path: "F:\Source\MyWebsite" and again I have confirmed that the .htaccess file does, indeed, exist.  I've also tried a variety of different ways to access the file path in the AddApacheModRewrite, but I'm really scratching my head on this one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had to use a streamreader, read the file, and then was able to apply it:

```
   using (StreamReader apacheModRewriteStreamReader 
           File.OpenText(env.ContentRootPath + "\\.htaccess")) 
   {                    
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
                          .AddApacheModRewrite(apacheModRewriteStreamReader);
                    
        app.UseRewriter(options);    
   }
```